# How to setDataSource in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, video-streaming, android-mediaplayer

This is the code but I keep getting an error on `setDataSource`, it works without an error when it's not in a fragment, so can someone please tell me how I can make it work?

```
try {
    player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    player.setDataSource(this, Uri.parse("http://www.example.com/example.mp4"));
    player.setOnPreparedListener(this);
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (SecurityException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IllegalStateException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
player.setDataSource(this, Uri.parse("http://www.example.com/example.mp4"));
```

to

```
player.setDataSource(getActivity(), Uri.parse("http://www.example.com/example.mp4"));
```

`setDataSource` takes an object of `Context` as a parameter. Since `Fragment` does not extend `Context` you can not use `this`.

But `Activity` extends `Context` so you can use `getActivity()`

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
player.setDataSource(this, Uri.parse("http://www.example.com/example.mp4"));
```

in fragment to :

```
player.setDataSource(this.getActivity(), Uri.parse("http://www.example.com/example.mp4"));
```